# list item selection in listbox blocks timer

Tags: ajax, timer, listbox

i have created a very simple chat program for educational reasons. The chat room consists of a textbox where the user writes the text message, a listbox where the text messages are appearing and a timer that every second refreshes the listbox inside an update panel. The aspx code is:

```html
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebChat.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebChatApp.WebChat" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/KeypressEvent.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </asp:ScriptManager>
        <div>
            <asp:Panel ID="PanelChatRoom" runat="server" Visible="False">
                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server" BackColor="Black" ForeColor="Red" Height="620px"
                            Width="668px" Enabled="False">
                        </asp:ListBox>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                    </ContentTemplate>
                    <Triggers>
                        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" EventName="Tick" />
                    </Triggers>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
                        <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" OnTick="Timer1_Tick" Interval="1000">
                        </asp:Timer>

                <asp:TextBox ID="txtmsg" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" onkeypress="CheckKeypress(event)"
                    Height="98px" Width="674px" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:HiddenField ID="hiddentxtvalue" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
            </asp:Panel>
        </div>
        <div>
            <asp:Panel ID="PanelUsername" runat="server">
                <asp:Label ID="lblusername" runat="server" Text="Label">Enter username :</asp:Label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtUserName" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:Button ID="bttnConnect" Text="Connect" runat="server" onclick="bttnConnect_Click"/>
                <asp:Label ID="lblmsg" runat="server" ForeColor="Red"></asp:Label>
            </asp:Panel>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

the C# code behind the file is:

```
public partial class WebChat : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label1.Text = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.ToString();
        Label2.Text = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.ToString();
        //means that enter was pressed by the user
        if (Request.Form["sendmsg"] != null)
        {
            UserTextContent usercont = new UserTextContent();
            usercont.userName = Session["username"].ToString();
            usercont.SetFullText(Request.Form["sendmsg"].ToString());

            lock (Global.lockqueueobj)
            {
                Global.chatContents.Enqueue(usercont);
                //check if the maximum rows limit was exceeded
                while (Global.chatContents.Count > Global.maxrows)
                {
                    Global.chatContents.Dequeue();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    protected void bttnConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bool usernameExists = false;
        if (txtUserName.Text == String.Empty)
        {
            lblmsg.Text = "please enter a username";
        }
        else
        {
            lock (Global.locklistobj)
            {
                foreach (string user in Global.users)
                {
                    if (user == txtUserName.Text)
                    {
                        lblmsg.Text = "username already exists. try another username";
                        usernameExists = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (usernameExists == false)
                {

                    Global.users.Add(txtUserName.Text);
                    Session["username"] = txtUserName.Text;
                    PanelUsername.Visible = false;
                    PanelChatRoom.Visible = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //ListBox1.Items.Clear();
        lock (Global.lockqueueobj)
        {
            if (Global.chatContents.Count > 0)
            {
                ListBox1.DataSource = Global.chatContents;
                ListBox1.DataTextField = "Text";
                ListBox1.DataBind();
            }
        }
        //ListBox1.ClearSelection();
    }
}
```

and the javascript file that sends the text message to the server is:

```js
function CheckKeypress(e) 
{
    if (e.keyCode == 13) 
    {
        var hiddentxt = document.getElementById("hiddentxtvalue");
        hiddentxt.value = "1";
        var txtmsg = document.getElementById("txtmsg");
        var msg = txtmsg.value;
        var name = "sendmsg";
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.open("POST", "WebChat.aspx", true);  //asynchronous posting
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState === 4 && xmlhttp.status === 200) {
                txtmsg.value = "";
            }
        };

        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        var data = name + "=" + msg;
        xmlhttp.send(data);
    }
}
```

The text messages are temporary stored into a Queue collection, which is defined together with some other variables in Global.asax.cs file:

```
    public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    public static Queue<UserTextContent> chatContents;
    public static List<string> users;
    public static object locklistobj;
    public static object lockqueueobj;
    public const int maxrows = 10;

    void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Code that runs on application startup
        chatContents = new Queue<UserTextContent>();
        users = new List<string>();
        locklistobj = new object();
        lockqueueobj = new object();
    }
```

the application works until the user selects an item inside the listbox and when that happens the timer stops working. Why? Any solution to the problem except of replacing the listbox with a textbox?

Answer (score 0):

i forgot to write also the use of the class UserTextContent:

```
    public class UserTextContent
{
    public string userName { get; set; }
    string text;
    StringBuilder FullText;

    public string Text
    {
        get { return this.text; }
    }

    public void SetFullText(string txt)
    {
        FullText = new StringBuilder();
        FullText.Append("<" + this.userName + ">");
        this.FullText.Append(txt);
        this.text = this.FullText.ToString();
    }
}
```